# Return boolean true or false in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am unable to get my function to return the statement provided when the Boolean value is false.

Tried adding Boolean() to the code, tried making every possible outcome look like

singleArg "0" || singleArg "something" etc

```js
function isTruthy(singleArg) {
  let isitTrue = '';
  if (singleArg === 'somecontent' || 1 || [2, 3, 4], {
      name: 'Alex'
    }) {
    isitTrue = true;
  } else if (singleArg === false || null || undefined || 0 || "") {
    isitTrue === 'The boolean value false is falsey';
    isitTrue === 'The null value is falsey';
    isitTrue === 'undefined is falsey';
    isitTrue === 'The number 0 is falsey';
    isitTrue == 'The empty string is falsey (the only falsey string)';
  }
  return isitTrue;
}

console.log(isTruthy(('somecontent')));
```

Write a function `isTruthy` that accepts a single argument of any type.

`isTruthy` should return true if that argument is 'truthy'.

If the value is 'falsey', log out one of the messages below, corresponding to
the type of the value tested.

Comment: `function isTruthy(singleArg){ return Boolean(singleArg); } `. Also your if statements are invalid.

Comment: You can't do this: `if (singleArg === false || null || undefined || 0 || "")`. You need to write it out completely, like `if (singleArg === false || singleArg === null` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is always going to return true, because you have in your first if block || 1.  Which always evaluates to true.

If you want `singleArg` to be compared to the value 1, then you need to write `singleArg === 'somecontent' || singleArg === 1 ...`

Also, for your second if block, all those values always evaluate to false.  You can actually simple write:

```
if (!singleArg)
```

Which will always return false whether the value is false, null, undefined, 0 or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As people have already pointed out, you can simply check `!Boolean(arg)`

Here's a suggestion on how to re-write the function:

```
function isTruthy(singleArg) {
  if ( !Boolean(singleArg) ) {
    switch( typeof singleArg ) {
      case "boolean":
        console.log( "The boolean value false is falsey" );
        break;

      case "object":  // typeof null is an object
        console.log( "The null value is falsey" );
        break;

      case "undefined":
        console.log( "undefined is falsey" );
        break;

      case "number":
        console.log( "The number 0 is falsey" );
        break;

      case "string":
        console.log( "The empty string is falsey (the only falsey string)" );
        break;

      default:
        console.log( "NaN?" );
        console.log( typeof singleArg );
        break;
    }
    return;
  }
  console.log( true );
}

isTruthy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and check the values directly.

In this case, with a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), you can omit a [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), because `return` terminates the execution of the function, hence the `switch`.

```js
function isTruthy(value) {
    switch (value) {
        case false:
            return 'The boolean value false is falsy';
        case null:
            return 'The null value is falsy';
        case undefined:
            return 'undefined is falsy';
        case 0:
            return 'The number 0 is falsy';
        case '':
            return 'The empty string is falsy (the only falsy string)';
    }
    return Boolean(value);
}

console.log(isTruthy(false));
console.log(isTruthy(null));
console.log(isTruthy(undefined));
console.log(isTruthy(0));
console.log(isTruthy(''));
console.log(isTruthy(NaN)); // false
console.log(isTruthy(true));
console.log(isTruthy({}));
console.log(isTruthy(1e3));
console.log(isTruthy('yes!'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```